# Manually call save_model on a button click?

Tags: python, django

So I added a button to my Django admin interface. This button on a precise model change view.
Let's take an example here :

```py
class MissionAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    # lot of blablablabla
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super(MissionAdmin, self).get_urls()
        custom_urls = patterns('',
                               url(r'^(?P<id>\d+)/validate/$', self.admin_site.admin_view(self.validate_and_save),
                                   name='admin_mission_validate_and_save'),)
        return custom_urls + urls
```

I display that button on my template manually and it refers to the validate url I defined just above.
Now in this method of my MissionAdmin class, I need to change the field called `status` and then save the whole thing just as if the user modified `status` himself and clicked on the `save` button.

Here is my problem though :
**I don't know how to save the model as if the user clicked on the `save` button.**

For now here is what I made :

```py
def validate_and_save(self, request, **kwargs):
        mission = get_object_or_404(Mission, **{'id': kwargs['id']})
        mission.status = Mission.VALIDATED
        # Need save the whole thing (model, inlines and stuff) right here.
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:me_core_mission_changelist'))
```

Does anyone know how I could perform a save manually ? It must take all changes made to the form. I already tried to call the save_model method like this :

```py
self.save_model(request, mission, self.form, True)
```

And it turn out that it saved only the status of the mission.

Comment: `form.save()` should fix your problem. Have a look at the docs (e.g. the [save method in forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) if you have foreign keys or m2m.

Comment: That sounds like an interesting approach. So do I have to call `self.form.save()` ? Will it also save the inlines ?

Comment: With inlines you should have a formset if I'm not mistaken. bound formsets have `save()` [methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/)